# Multithread https requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm trying to multi-thread web requests in python for web scraping. I want to send multiple requests to the same website using multi-threading, but the time it takes for the script to complete is the same whether or not I use multi-threading.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import queue
import urllib.request
from threading import Thread


def perform_web_requests(addresses, no_workers):
    class Worker(Thread):
        def __init__(self, request_queue):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.queue = request_queue
            self.results = []

        def run(self):
            while True:
                content = self.queue.get()
                if content == "":
                    break
                request = urllib.request.Request(content)
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
                self.results.append(response.read())
                self.queue.task_done()

    # Create queue and add addresses
    q = queue.Queue()
    for url in addresses:
        q.put(url)

    # Workers keep working till they receive an empty string
    for _ in range(no_workers):
        q.put("")

    # Create workers and add tot the queue
    workers = []
    for _ in range(no_workers):
        worker = Worker(q)
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)
    # Join workers to wait till they finished
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()

    # Combine results from all workers
    r = []
    for worker in workers:
        r.extend(worker.results)
    return r


urls = ['https://google.com']
i = 0
while i < 100:
    results = perform_web_requests(urls, 50)
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears urllib does not support multi-threading. Use urllib3:
https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3